# update curl on centos5

Tags: yum, curl, upgrade

i have centos 5.9, with curl 7.15.5. i need curl 7.16.2+ .

i'm a novice webmaster...if that. but would like to try.

what are the commands to add a yum rpm repo so i can update the curl version, if this makes sense?

is his of any use: http://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if it will work with the rpm:s you're linking to.

Downnload and install the sourcerpm,    `curl-7.32.0-2.0.cf.fc12.src.rpm` from that link, or get `curl-7.27.0-12.fc18.src.rpm` from fedora repos.

then get the `yum-utils` package and run:

```
sudo yum-builddep curl-7.32.0-2.0.cf.fc10.src.rpm
```

then install the source package, `rpmbuild` it and you'll get the rpm needed.

You can do this on a separate build box.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just download the rpm directly and install it:

Let's take `curl-7.32.0-2.0.cf.fc10.x86_64.rpm` for example.

`wget http://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/curl-7.32.0-2.0.cf.fc10.x86_64.rpm`

`rpm -i curl-7.32.0-2.0.cf.fc10.x86_64.rpm`

There may be dependencies for `curl` that you will need to update/install as well.